# Javascript access variables in prototype without instantiating

Tags: javascript, prototype

Is it bad practice to access variables in a javascript class without instantiating it?

For example:

```
var Test = function(){
  this.tests.push("Something");
}
Test.prototype.tests = [];

var test = new Test();

console.log(Test.prototype.tests); //Is this okay to do? Obviously I can use test.test here, but this is a poor example of why I am wanting to do this; it merely shows my question.
```

I've run across an instance where I only have an id and I want to use the class to get the correct instance of itself for me such that: `Test.prototype.getByID(id);` but I wanted to make sure it is proper to do this.

Comment: The prototype is *distinct* from any instances that are linked to it - remember that the prototype is just a *shared* object in the property resolution chain and so `tests` works a bit like a "class static" variable here. In the above code, `"Something"` will be appended to the [shared] array in the prototype object each time a new instance is created (really, each time `Test` is invoked).

Comment: I don't like this approach (I'd much rather create an external collection/map and explicitly use that), but the outlined approach will "work". Just be careful (as it's especially easy in this case) to not keep unused objects permanently-alive.

Comment: Thanks, just to be certain you didn't make a mistake, are you saying it IS easy to keep the object permanently alive because there is always a reference to the object so the garbage collection won't get it, or the other way around?

Comment: I mean, `this.idMap[someKey] = this` called from a constructor could be forgotten to be cleaned up when relevant (while `prototype.idMap` would remain strongly reachable) - just something to watch out for, as it might bite in degenerate cases. If having to add the objects to an external collection, I find it's easier to keep track of the external collection - and simply let it lose reachability so the GC can clean up the entire sub-object graph automatically. In any case, document the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take advantage of closures in JavaScript and do something like the following ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v4g4U/)).  This has the advantage of making your "list of tests" private so it can't be messed with and you don't have to access the `prototype` which does feel a bit odd:

```
var Test = (function() {
    var tests = {};

    var Test = function(id){
        tests[id] = this;
        this.id = id;
    }

    Test.getByID = function(id) {
        return tests[id];
    }

    return Test;
}());

var test1 = new Test(1);
var test2 = new Test(2);

var test2_2 = Test.getByID(2);

alert( test1 === test2_2 );//should be false
alert( test2 === test2_2 );//should be true
```

Comment: Yeah, I've used this method before, but was curious as to the "propers" of whether I can do what I mentioned above.